# LBP2 Infinite Loading Screen Glitch - Hangs/Stuck at "Important Information" at Startup

Tags: technical-issues, little-big-planet-2

I haven't played Little Big Planet 2 in months.  After all the updates were *finally* done downloading and installing, I started up the game, only to find that it hangs at the "Important Information" screen forever.

Apparently there was a similar loading-screen glitch when the game was launched.  The solution was to turn your controller off, and turn it back on when the game had loaded.  However, that does not work this time.

**How can I get the game to load?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed this about a week ago, but the solution was hard to find, and apparently since then the [forum I found it on](http://forums.littlebigworkshop.com/t5/PS3-General-Discussion/Little-Big-Planet-2-Freezes-During-Load/td-p/389662) has been taken down *(!?)*

I am posting the question/solution here so others in the future don't have to go through the same trouble I did >_<

---

**Steps to solve** *(requires two controllers)*

1. Make sure the second PS3 controller is **off**.
2. Create a new user account in your PS3 *(the left-most option from the main menu)* and log into it.

   - *You **don't** need to associate it with a PSN account or a credit card, or anything like that*
3. Run Little Big Planet 2 from the new account.  It should load correctly.
4. Play through the intro/tutorial until you get to your pod.
5. Turn on your second controller, and choose your main account.
6. Once your character loads and falls into the pod, LBP2 should work correctly from your main account.  You can exit the game, switch to your main account, and try playing LBP2 again.